# Common event handler for all Google Maps v3 markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I have a map that shows 500 markers and they are redrawn when the user scrolls the map. Each of the markers is quite complicated - they're numbered and have click, mouseover and mouseout (to animate them) events attached. This causes some performance issues because removing and adding these markers takes a lot of time. I've been wondering if I could attach a single click, mouseover and mouseout event handlers for the whole map and catch the event that bubbles up from the markers there. Is this possible? Would it improve the performance?

I've found this - [How do I make a single event handler for all markers in Google Maps V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319400/how-do-i-make-a-single-event-handler-for-all-markers-in-google-maps-v3) - it's better, but it still requires attaching the handler to each of the markers separately.

I've also found Google Maps Data Layers - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#add_event_handlers - it looks like there's only one event attached for the whole layer, but I'm not sure if it doesn't attach it to each of the markers internally anyway. I'm also not sure if the additional level of abstraction won't slow the things down.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: I wouldn't bother too much about what it does internally. Try it and see if the performance gets improved. From what I understand, the purpose is to avoid iterating through each overlay to set styles and event listeners, so I'd expect it to be quicker but I never tried that.

Comment: Have you try thread in javascript ?? 
(function(markeri){
 // Event here
})(marker);

Comment: I don't understand why you are "removing and adding these markers"... does the user scroll the map to a totally different region and you have to create 500 new markers? do you only have to remove markers from the non-visible area and add some new ones ? Can you avoid "new google.maps.Marker()" by repositioning old ones ?

Comment: For simplicity we always remove and add everything. We could implement some more complicated algorithm to redraw only what has changed, but as you mentioned, complete redraw would still be need if the user scrolls far enough. However, repositioning is an interesting idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved all our problems by enabling the "optimized" flag on our markers. Then the markers are rendered on the map canvas and they aren't visible in the DOM, which also means that there are no event handlers attached to them directly. We implemented interactivity by creating div elements on the fly when a marker is hovered. Everything is much smoother now.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue and found the solution by making clusters: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

This helps a lot and is actually faster than placing everything in arrays, and pushing them to the map 1 by one

You can keep the events for each marker and group them + make it clustered.

Comment: Right, but I want to avoid clustering - that's why I limit the number of markers to 500. To use that clusterer I'd need to return all the markers (tens of thousands) data in one JSON response from the server. This causes new problems - more work for the server, more data to transfer etc and most of the markers won't be seen by the users anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a real estate search engine a few years ago. Think a stock google map overlayed with hundreds, thousands, tens of thousands of markers.

We found that tile overlays on top of google maps were the best performing solution. Overlays are supported in the maps API and can be used in place of markers to show objects on the map with minimal lag. They make a good substitute for use cases which would otherwise require a large number of markers.

Using tools such as mapserver its fairly easily to generate the tiles. In conjunction with the tiles you also need to write a custom click handler and likely a webservice which resolves coordinates to an individual marker and returns data for that marker.

Comment: Right, this is probably the best solution for supporting thousands of markers. However, our markers are more interactive - they have hover effects for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few tests and found out that it is actually slower to use the `loadGeoJson` method of the `google.maps.Data` class than to use a standard jQuery AJAX call.

I have tested it with a JSON with around 7000 entries, creating/plotting a marker for each entry and binding a click event on each marker.

Here are the results of the scripting time in Chrome (average of 10 requests):

- **With loadGeoJson:**

> **Average: 3.156s** | High: 3.69s | Low: 2.75s

- **Standard AJAX request:**

> **Average: 1.795s** | High: 2.01s | Low: 1.66s

Now if loading 500 markers is really slow on your end, you might want to expose your code so that we have an idea of how you do it. Maybe there is something that can be improved in the way you load/reload/remove your markers?

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's good to know that loadGeoJson is slower. Would you be so kind to compare the standard AJAX and adding Features to the data layer manually? (Then you can also bind only one event handler for all the markers) - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.Feature

It isn't very slow - 200ms on my desktop. The problem is that it causes my Ajax handler to freeze the browser for that time. I fire that request while uses scrolls the map or changes some filters and this amount of time is noticeable - the UX isn't smooth. Also, it becomes worse on mobile devices.